# <center> en Imagen no funciona correctamente

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Las imágenes tienen que estar tal y como están una encima de la otra, ya que esa es la idea principal.

Pero como se puede ver el texto lo centra correctamente, pero la imagen no.

**¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?**

```css
body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background: #f2f2f2;
}
.my-navbar{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border:none;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
}
.div-image{
    margin:50px auto;
    float:none;
    min-height: 350px;
    transition: color 1s, font-size 1s;
}
.div-image:hover{
    color: rgb(90,200,120);
    font-size: 20px;
}
.static-image{
    position: absolute;
}
.rotate-image{
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: transform .2s;
    transition: transform 1s, margin-left .6s, margin-top .6s;
}
.rotate-image:hover{
    transform: rotate(15deg);
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.center-element{
    margin:0px auto !important;
    float:none !important;
}
.no-margin{
    margin: 0px !important;
}
.no-padding{
    padding: 0px !important;
}
.white-text{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.black-text{
    color: #000000;
}
.gray-text{
    color: #c9c9c9;
}
.red-text{
    color: #AE2629;
}
.blue-text{
    color: #18666A;

}
```

```html
<article class="row" id="ip6">
             <center><h1>iPhone</h1></center>
             <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
              <div class="div-image">
               <center><h4>Probando cosas</h4>
      <img class="static-image" src="https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4662/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/i/ph/iphone7/jetblack/iphone7-jetblack-select-2016_AV2?wid=150&hei=305&fmt=png-alpha&qlt=95&.v=1472693558353">
      <img class="rotate-image" src="https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4662/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/i/ph/iphone7/jetblack/iphone7-jetblack-select-2016_AV1?wid=150&hei=305&fmt=png-alpha&qlt=95&.v=1472693193136"></center>
                 </div>
             </div>
            
     </article>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hay un par de cosas que no deberías hacer.

**No uses la etiqueta** `<center>`

Es [obsoleta](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html) a partir de HTML5 y ya no tiene más soporte. Así que, dada su estado obsoleto los navegadores ya no la interpretarán como antes en un futuro. Para centrar una imagen puedes hacerlo simplemente vía CSS, mediante las propiedades `text-align` o `margin`.

**Evita usar demasiado** `absolute`

Si tienes varios elementos posicionados como absolutos, será complicado hacerlos responsivos. Lo mejor es definir un flujo para los elementos y poder así hacerlos responsivos. Los elementos absolutos por general se usan para cosas bastante específicas, como por ejemplo, el botón "subir", animaciones, menús flotantes, etc.

---

He tocado un poco de tu código. Las imágenes ahora están agrupadas en un contenedor `.images`, la cual tiene una posición `relative` para poder tener la imagen "flotante" perfectamente alineada con la estática solamente con un `left: 0`. Además, `#ip6` tiene la propiedad `text-align: center` para centrar los `h1` y los `.div-image`.

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

#ip6 {
  text-align: center;
}

.div-image {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 50px auto;
  float: none;
  min-height: 350px;
  transition: color 1s, font-size 1s;
}

.div-image:hover {
  color: rgb(90, 200, 120);
  font-size: 20px;
}

.images {
  position: relative;
}

.rotate-image {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transition: transform 1s, margin-left .6s, margin-top .6s;
}

.rotate-image:hover {
  transform: rotate(15deg);
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<article class="row" id="ip6">
  <h1>iPhone</h1>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
    <div class="div-image">
      <h4>Probando cosas</h4>
      <article class="images">
        <img class="static-image" src="https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4662/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/i/ph/iphone7/jetblack/iphone7-jetblack-select-2016_AV2?wid=150&hei=305&fmt=png-alpha&qlt=95&.v=1472693558353">
        <img class="rotate-image" src="https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4662/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/i/ph/iphone7/jetblack/iphone7-jetblack-select-2016_AV1?wid=150&hei=305&fmt=png-alpha&qlt=95&.v=1472693193136">
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 2):

El center funciona correctamente.

Si miras la esquina superior izq de la imagen, ves que ese punto coincide con la mitad del `div div-image`. Tenemos que hacer que el centro de la imagen esté en el centro de el `div`.

Lo que puedes hacer es añadir un `transform` para que mueva esas imagenes un 50% de su tamaño a la izq.

> ```
> transform: translate(-50%);
> ```

Ejemplo:

```
.static-image{
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}
.rotate-image{
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: transform .2s;
    transition: transform 1s, margin-left .6s, margin-top .6s;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

```css
body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background: #f2f2f2;
}
.my-navbar{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    border:none;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
}
.div-image{
    margin:50px auto;
    float:none;
    min-height: 350px;
    transition: color 1s, font-size 1s;
}
.div-image:hover{
    color: rgb(90,200,120);
    font-size: 20px;
}
.static-image{
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%);
}
.rotate-image{
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: transform .2s;
    transition: transform 1s, margin-left .6s, margin-top .6s;
    transform: translate(-50%);
    
}
.rotate-image:hover{
    transform: rotate(15deg);
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.center-element{
    margin:0px auto !important;
    float:none !important;
}
.no-margin{
    margin: 0px !important;
}
.no-padding{
    padding: 0px !important;
}
.white-text{
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.black-text{
    color: #000000;
}
.gray-text{
    color: #c9c9c9;
}
.red-text{
    color: #AE2629;
}
.blue-text{
    color: #18666A;

}
```

```html
<article class="row" id="ip6">
             <center><h1>iPhone</h1></center>
             <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
              <div class="div-image">
               <center><h4>Probando cosas</h4>
      <img class="static-image" src="https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4662/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/i/ph/iphone7/jetblack/iphone7-jetblack-select-2016_AV2?wid=150&hei=305&fmt=png-alpha&qlt=95&.v=1472693558353">
      <img class="rotate-image" src="https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4662/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/i/ph/iphone7/jetblack/iphone7-jetblack-select-2016_AV1?wid=150&hei=305&fmt=png-alpha&qlt=95&.v=1472693193136"></center>
                 </div>
             </div>
            
     </article>
```

Answer (score -1):

Por algún motivo, no sabría responderte cual, la imagen se centra en referencia al título, he probado sin usar las etiquetas center y usando text-align: center, pero ocurria lo mismo.

La solución que he encontrado ha sido la siguiente: sacar las imágenes fuera de center modificando esas lineas del siguiente modo:

```
<div class="div-image">
  <center><h4>Probando cosas</h4></center>
  <div style="width:150px;margin:0 auto">
    <img class="static-image" src="https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4662/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/i/ph/iphone7/jetblack/iphone7-jetblack-select-2016_AV2?wid=150&amp;hei=305&amp;fmt=png-alpha&amp;qlt=95&amp;.v=1472693558353">
    <img class="rotate-image" src="https://store.storeimages.cdn-apple.com/4662/as-images.apple.com/is/image/AppleInc/aos/published/images/i/ph/iphone7/jetblack/iphone7-jetblack-select-2016_AV1?wid=150&amp;hei=305&amp;fmt=png-alpha&amp;qlt=95&amp;.v=1472693193136">
  </div>
</div>
```