# ¿Cómo puedo centrar icono en el menú de navegación y que se mantenga en todos los dispositivo?

Tags: html, html5, css

Estoy realizando mi primera pagina web y lo que intento hacer es centrar el icono que está en el menú de navegación y que se mantenga centrado al usarlo en cualquier dispositivo. Al estirar el navegador que siga estando centrado.

*Un ejemplo claro de lo que quiero hacer lo pueden encontrar en la página oficial de Apple*

```css
.menu nav .logo {
  background-image: url("../contenido/logo.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 140px;
  height: 45px;
  background-size: 140px;
  float: left;
  z-index: 998;
}
```

```html
<header class="menu">
  <nav>
    <div class="botonMenu">
      <div class="rayaDelMenu"></div>
      <a class="logo" href="#"></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Trabajo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Trabajo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Trabajo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Trabajo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Trabajo</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: No está muy claro lo que pretendes hacer, por favor publica una imagen de ese icono o de lo que quieras resolver

Comment: Arevalo, mira [esta pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52396/center-en-imagen-no-funciona-correctamente/52400#52400), me lo recordaste con lo de Apple

Comment: Us los tamaños con % y no px. De esta manera te mantendra la relacion a la pantalla.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.menu nav .logo {
      background-image: url("../contenido/logo.png");
      width: 140px;
      height: 45px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
    }
```

```html
<header class="menu">
  <nav>
    <div class="botonMenu">
      <div class="rayaDelMenu"></div>
      <a class="logo" href="#"></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Trabajo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Trabajo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Trabajo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Trabajo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Trabajo</a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Es muy sencillo de solucionar con "Flexbox". Prueba con este CSS:

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente debes añadir el estilo `margin:auto`, a tu `div.botonMenu`, asi que también el estilo `display:inline-block`. Para hacerlo exactamente igual a apple deberías usar media queries y ajustar la posición de los botones según el tamaño del dispositivo.

```
@media screen and (max-width:750px)
{
  /*Aqui pones el codigo para cuando la pantalla sea menos ancha que 750px*/
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

pero para un centrado absoluto del logo, es conveniente hacerlo de forma absoluta, esto es, haciendo el logo `position: absolute` y dando un `top` y `left` del 50% para finalmente usar `transform` para invertir dicha cantidad, de tal modo que por el contraste se centre absolutamente, tanto horizontal como verticalmente.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
}

.menu nav .botonMenu {
  align-items: center;
  /display: flex;
  height: 50px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  line-height: 50px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu nav .botonMenu .rayaDelMenu {
  color: #555;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  height: 22px;
}

.menu nav .botonMenu .rayaDelMenu i {
  font-size: 22px;
  vertical-align: sub;
}

.menu nav .logo {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/7klrTiy.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 998;
}

.menu nav ul {
  float: right;
}

.menu nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 12px;
}

.menu nav ul li a {
  color: #555;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<header class="menu">
  <nav>
    <div class="botonMenu">
      <div class="rayaDelMenu">
        <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
      </div>
      <a class="logo" href="#"></a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Usuarios</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Preguntas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ayuda</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Para alinear el botón del menú y las opciones, puedes usar `float` o puedes hacerlo con flexbox como lo indica la otra respuesta: `align-items: center; display: flex; height: 50px; justify-content: space-between;`.